# How to find zeros

Tags: linear-algebra

How to count the number of zeros at the end of the number
$6^5×2^{12}×5^8×3^8$? 
To count this I have considered to multiply 5 with even number but still confused to solve it.

Comment: You need a pair of $(2, 5$) to get a $0$ in the end. How many such pairs can you find? What is the limiting factor here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT:

We have exactly $8$ powers of $5,$

As $5\cdot2=10,$ we need exactly one even number to be paired with each $5$

We clearly have $12>8, 2$s available as multipler

Had the power of $2$ been $<8,$ we could pair each surviving $5$  with one $6$ each

Comment: So we will have 8 zeros at the end ?

Comment: @mathphy, any doubt:)

Comment: I'm little skeptic nothing else :D

Comment: @mathphy, what is most important is the method is understandable or not? Right answer will follow the right method

Comment: If the question asked for $200!$ then what would be the easiest ,method to get?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/295643/with-how-many-zeros-it-ends

Comment: I got the method but how to find the number number of 5 and 2 ?

Comment: @mathphy, the power of $5$ in $200!$ will be $\displaystyle=\sum_{1\le <\infty}\left\lfloor\frac{200}{5^r}\right\rfloor$

Now, $\left\lfloor\frac{200}{5}\right\rfloor=40,$ $\left\lfloor\frac{200}{5^2}\right\rfloor=8,$ $\left\lfloor\frac{200}{5^3}\right\rfloor=1$ and we have much higher power of $2$ available in $200!$ (as in the answer)